# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'UIViewController' when creating a protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to define my protocol so that the class implementing it has to also be a `UIViewController`.

So i typed the following code into a header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIViewController.h>
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>
#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>

@protocol MySuperProtocol<UIViewController> // <-- here

@property(nonatomic, weak, nullable) id<EKEventViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

I always get the error saying that:

> Cannot find protocol declaration for 'UIViewController'

If i replace `UIViewController` with `NSObject`, code compiles. If i remove the `<>` inheritance after the protocol, code compiles.

I tried all combinations of

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIViewController.h>
```

to no avail.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the syntax.  `@protocol MySuperProtocol<UIViewController>` doesn't establish a constraint that implementers of `MySuperProtocol` must be `UIViewController`s.  It says that `MySuperProtocol` conforms to `UIViewController`

However, unlike `NSObject`, `UIViewController` is not a protocol; it is a class.  A protocol cannot conform to a class, only to another protocol.

You can refer to the documentation:

> [**Protocols inherit from other protocols**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW9)
>
> In the same way that an Objective-C class can inherit from a superclass, you can also specify that one protocol conforms to another.

There is no way to constrain protocol adoption in Objective C.